# Google analytics api: requestReportData by weeks instead of days?

Tags: php, date, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This is how I am getting the pageviews of a url for a custom interval (usually the date of creation of the url and the present)

```
$ga->requestReportData(
    $ga_profile_id,
    array('date'),
    array('pageviews'),
    'date', 
    'pagePath == '.$ga_url, 
    $ga_start, /* Creaton day */
    date("Y-m-d", strtotime("0 day", time())), /* Today */
    null,
    1000
);
$results = $ga->getResults();
```

The thing is that some of the urls are old and then my chart looks too saturated:

[image]

So I would like to check the value of the interval in days, and if its big enough; get the pageviews by weeks (and then if its big enough, maybe in months?)

Is it posible?

This is how I am generating the Chart, by the way:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    <!-- Create the data table -->
    data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Lecturas');

    <!-- Fill the chart with the data pulled from Analtyics. Each row matches the order setup by the columns: day then pageviews -->
    data.addRows([
      <?php
      foreach($results as $result) {
          echo '["'.date('M j',strtotime($result->getDate())).'", '.$result->getPageviews().'],';
      }
      ?>
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 630, height: 180, title: '<?php echo  $ga_start.' - '. date("Y-m-d", strtotime("0 day", time())); ?>',
                      colors:['#999999','#ff0000'],
                      areaOpacity: 0.1,
                      hAxis: {textPosition: 'in', showTextEvery: 30, slantedText: false, textStyle: { color: '#555555', fontSize: 10 } },
                      pointSize: 5,
                      legend: 'none',
                      chartArea:{left:0,top:30,width:"100%",height:"100%"}
    });
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using an old version of the Client Lib for php? Instead of the newer version at: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Well I implemented this more than a year a go... @DaImTo

Comment: That client lib hasn't been developed on since 2009 I'm checking the code. I wonder if its going to prevent you from doing something's. Like the error your getting in the comment you posted to the answer below.   Its reading from what I think is the first version of the API, its prior to v2.4 anyway.  Changing to the new one isn't going to be easy for you as it returns json and not xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `date` as a dimension in your query is retrieving pageviews per day -- you can use `week` or `month` dimensions instead.

See [Time - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_week)

Make sure to change both the dimension and the sort parameters, like

```
$ga->requestReportData(
  $ga_profile_id,
  array('week'),
  array('pageviews'),
  'week', 
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried `week` but the I get this error: `
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "GDatabadRequestSort key ga:week is not a dimension or metric in this query."`

Comment: Did you put it in exactly as "ga:week"? If so I think your client lib adds the ga: for you try and remove that.

Comment: The `GDatabadRequestSort` msg says you're trying to sort by a dimension not specified in the query -- did you put week in both the dimension and sort parameters?